# How to upload files in ionic 3 by using drag and drop feature

Tags: file-upload

I am trying to upload file by using `"Image Picker"` plugin of `ionic 3` but this plugin not working with browser in desktop, after that I tried normal html input tag which allows select files using file explorer, but I want something which can upload pictures by drag and drop. Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried these, you can use any one as per your need :-
1:- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-file-drop

2:- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-uploader

3:-  https://www.joshmorony.com/multi-file-upload-with-ionic-angular-client-side/